# show flash in an aspx page?

Tags: asp.net

what's wrong with my code? it shows the flash in fire fox but not in chrome and IE8

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="UI_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
html,body { height: 100%;width:100% }
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#d3d3d3" style="margin:0px;">
<!--url's used in the movie-->
<!--text used in the movie-->
<!-- saved from url=(0013)about:internet -->
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="100%" height="100%" id="home" align="middle">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
    <param name="movie" value="home.swf" /><param name="menu" value="false" />
    <param name="quality" value="High" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#d3d3d3" /> 
        <embed src="../swf/home.swf" menu="false" quality="High" wmode="transparent" bgcolor="#d3d3d3" width="100%" height="100%" name="home" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **src** param tag in **object** tagobject Tag

```
<param  name="src" value="../swf/home.swf" />
```

AS

```
<object 
    classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" 
    codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" 
    width="100%" 
    height="100%" 
    id="home" 
    align="middle">     
    <param  name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />     
    <param  name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />     
    <param  name="movie" value="home.swf" />
    <param  name="menu" value="false" />     
    <param  name="quality" value="High" />
    <param  name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param  name="bgcolor"  value="#d3d3d3" />          
    <param  name="src" value="../swf/home.swf" />       
    <embed  src="../swf/home.swf" menu="false" quality="High" wmode="transparent" bgcolor="#d3d3d3" width="100%" height="100%" name="home" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />     
</object>
```

please try this sample it working for me in IE,FireFox and Chromw

```
<object id='mySwf' classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' codebase='http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab' style='width:100%;height:100%;'>
            <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
            <param name='src' value='../swf/home.swf'/>
            <param name='flashVars' value=''/>
            <embed id='embedSwf' 
                src='../swf/home.swf' 
                pluginspage='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer' 
                width='100%' height='100%'
                flashVars=''
                /> 
        </object>
```

Comment: thanks, I tried it. now it works in IE and fire fox but not in chrome. why?

Comment: The problem was "movie" param it should change to "../swf/home.swf"

Answer (score 0):

It wont be a server side issue (unless you have code that modifies output based on user agent).

The issue is probably you don't have Flash installed on Chrome and IE8.  Try reinstalling it and running it to see if it works.